# /usr/bin/systemctl start openstack-nova-api failed

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

Getting error when installing packstack.

```
ERROR : Error appeared during Puppet run: x.x.x.x_api_nova.pp
Error: Could not start Service[nova-api]: Execution of '/usr/bin/systemctl start openstack-nova-api' returned 1: Job for openstack-nova-api.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status openstack-nova-api.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
You will find full trace in log /var/tmp/packstack/20160426-103906-Zre0yo/manifests/x.x.x.x_api_nova.pp.log'


Apr 26 10:50:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit openstack-nova-api.service entered failed state.
Apr 26 10:50:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: openstack-nova-api.service failed.
Apr 26 10:50:13 localhost.localdomain setroubleshoot[6359]: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/python2.7 from getattr access on the file /usr/bin/rpm. For comple
Apr 26 10:50:13 localhost.localdomain python[6359]: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/python2.7 from getattr access on the file /usr/bin/rpm.

                                                    *****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

                                                    If you believe that python2.7 should be allowed getattr access on the rpm file by default.
                                                    Then you should report this as a bug.
                                                    You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
                                                    Do
                                                    allow this access for now by executing:
                                                    # grep nova-novncproxy /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
                                                    # semodule -i mypol.pp

Apr 26 10:50:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: openstack-nova-api.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 26 10:50:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting OpenStack Nova API Server...
-- Subject: Unit openstack-nova-api.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit openstack-nova-api.service has begun starting up.
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain python2[9047]: detected unhandled Python exception in '/usr/bin/nova-api'
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain nova-api[9047]: error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain nova-api[9047]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain nova-api[9047]: File "/usr/bin/nova-api", line 10, in <module>
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain nova-api[9047]: sys.exit(main())
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain nova-api[9047]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/cmd/api.py", line 41, in main
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain nova-api[9047]: config.parse_args(sys.argv)
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain nova-api[9047]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/config.py", line 65, in parse_args
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain nova-api[9047]: default_config_files=default_config_files)
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain nova-api[9047]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2171, in __call__
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain nova-api[9047]: self._namespace._files_permission_denied)
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain nova-api[9047]: oslo_config.cfg.ConfigFilesPermissionDeniedError: Failed to open some config files: /etc/nova/nova.conf
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain setroubleshoot[6359]: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/python2.7 from getattr access on the file /usr/bin/rpm. For comple
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain python[6359]: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/python2.7 from getattr access on the file /usr/bin/rpm.

                                                    *****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

                                                    If you believe that python2.7 should be allowed getattr access on the rpm file by default.
                                                    Then you should report this as a bug.
                                                    You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
                                                    Do
                                                    allow this access for now by executing:
                                                    # grep nova-novncproxy /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
                                                    # semodule -i mypol.pp

Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: openstack-nova-api.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenStack Nova API Server.
-- Subject: Unit openstack-nova-api.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit openstack-nova-api.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit openstack-nova-api.service entered failed state.
Apr 26 10:50:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: openstack-nova-api.service failed.
'
```

Comment: Please read how SO rendered your log dump. Also, this site is for programming questions, which yours isn't. Lastly, without showing any effort (see the question guidelines for inspiration), you will probably not get help in any community, so consider hiring a professional.

Comment: Try to read and understand this line: `ConfigFilesPermissionDeniedError: Failed to open some config files: /etc/nova/nova.conf`

Comment: Have you tried disabling selinux or adding the correct selinux policies? That error is coming up a lot: `SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/python2.7 from getattr access on the file /usr/bin/rpm`

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it looks like an SELinux issue: `SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/python2.7 from getattr access on the file /usr/bin/rpm`

You can either disable selinux or use audit2allow to get the permissions it needs and add it with `sedmodule`. It says what to run in the logs:

```
# grep nova-novncproxy /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
# semodule -i mypol.pp
```